# Check if falsy except zero in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, standards

I am checking if a value is not falsy with

```
if (value) {
  ..
}
```

but I do want to accept zeros as a (non-falsy) value. How is this normally done? Would it be

```
if (value || value === 0) {
  ..
}
```

or what?

Answer (score 68):

```
if (value || value === 0) {
  ..
}
```

is cleaner way, no problem.

Just for fun try this

```
val = 0;
if(val){
console.log(val)
}
//outputs 0   **update - it used to be.. but now it seems it doesnt in chrome
```

And

```
var val = 0;
if(val){
console.log(val)
}
//outputs nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't understand why `console.log` doesn't print anything for the second example?

Comment: I tried in node8 and for both the examples `console.log` didn't print anything.

Answer (score 19):

I would use `value || value === 0`. It's fine whichever way you do it but IMO this is the cleanest option.

Answer (score 6):

**3 frequently useful condition checks:**

1. Filters **all falsy** [ *0, null, undefined, NaN, empty, string (""), false* ]

   ```
   if(!value) 
   {
     // some non-falsy value
   }
   ```
2. checks if the **value** is **exist** and also **defined**

   ```
   if(typeof value!== 'undefined') 
   {
     // value is exist and also defined
   }
   ```
3. checks all falsy - **except** value **0**

   ```
   if (value || value === 0) 
   {
     ....
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

For answer completeness, you can also just check for the other falsey values.

```js
if (value !== false && value !== undefined && value !== null && value !== '') {

}
```

You can even check for a number to catch the zero, besides your example of checking for zero itself

```js
if (!isNAN(value) || value) {
}
```

Your example is the most succinct though, and also requires the least amount of processing.

```js
if (value === 0 || value) {
}
```