# Vuetify Vaildation

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

For the Offical doc, it provides that checking for the form. But is it possible to exclude "0" as an invalid value?

```
required: (value) => !!value || "Required.",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tweak the condition to [accept zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626876/check-if-falsy-except-zero-in-javascript) as well.

```html
<v-text-field v-model="firstname" :rules="required" label="First name"/>
```

```js
data: () => ({
  firstname: "",
  required: [value => !!(value || value === 0) || "Name is required"]
})
```

[image]

Here's a demo at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-snowflake-r0z37?file=/src/components/Playground.vue:0-236).