# How to change this js condition in a way that will ignore the 0 case in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have the following condition.

```
if (!product.tag_id) {
  return;
}
```

How can I change it in a way that for the tag_id which is equal to 0 it will not return wrong thing. Now it considers tag_id:0  as false value and returns nothing. How can be it fixed?

Comment: You should test for the specific `false` value with `===`. Or if you want to know if there's a `tag_id` property at all, use `if (!("tag_id" in product))`

Comment: is it this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626876/check-if-falsy-except-zero-in-javascript

Comment: `if(!product.hasOwnProperty("tage_id")) {return}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-specific-property-in-javascript

Comment: It's not really clear what you *want* the condition to do. What values can `product` (or `product.tag_id`) have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if (!product.tag_id && product.tag_id !== 0) return;
// Do something else
```

This checks for if the product tag id is **not** equal to zero before returning.

Comment: I might add that if tag_id should be, or is a number, you could coerce it to one like +product.tag_id.  Then this expression becomes more simple with product.tag_id !==0 or maybe just product.tag_id > 0